# I am facing backend model error in magento when i moved project from lcoalhost to server

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes

I am facing  backend model error when i moved project from localhost to live server. error detail is.

```
Invalid backend model specified: sse_autosku/entity_attribute_backend_increment
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to search `sse_autosku/entity_attribute_backend_increment` text with your database. You will find this entry in `eav_attribute` table, and null this entry in your row. If you are not using `Sse_Autosku` module in your Magento setup.

If you are using this module in your setup then there must be `capitalization` mistake in this module

Comment: Thanks Keyur shah. what you means by 'capitalization' mistake?

Comment: mighe be some spell or english capital text problem @KhalilurRehman

Comment: same source was working on another server with all functionalities but as i moved to another server its showing errors.

Answer (score 0):

On server locate the module Sse/Autosku it will exist on either app/code/community or app/code/local

In that module folder does the path and file exist?

Entity/Attribute/Backend/Increment.php

( case is important )

If it exists. Check file permissions.

Comment: I have placed file on the location as you said on Entity/Attribute/Backend/Increment.php, but now giving error.                        Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Increment in /home/msm/public_html/sewingapis/app/code/core/Mage/Sse/Autosku/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Increment.php on line 50

Comment: Sound like you did not copy the site entirely AS IS from old location to new. I suggest you re-look at how you did the site transfer. Your issue is not solvable by anyone, as you have not faithfully reproduced your site to the new server. Alternatively you did not transfer your db over from old to new.